# Posting into Facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I need to post to Facebook page using API.

I am logged in as the page and I use app with some configuration.

```
var access;
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
console.log('statusChangeCallback');
access = response.authResponse.accessToken;
// The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
// app know the current login status of the person.
// Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
// for FB.getLoginStatus().
if (response.status === 'connected') {
  // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  testAPI();
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
  // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into this app.';
} else {
  // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
  // they are logged into this app or not.
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into Facebook.';
}
}

// This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
// Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
// code below.
function checkLoginState() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
});
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
 appId      : '679960325437732',
 cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                    // the session
 xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
 version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
});

// Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
// FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
// person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
// the callback you provide.  They can be:
//
// 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
// 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
// 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
//    your app or not.
//
// These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
var page;
// Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
// successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
function testAPI() {
FB.api('/369847826459197', function(response) {
    page = response;
    $('#facebook-login-button').css('display', 'none');
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'You are Logged in Facebook as ' + response.name + '!';

});

}



function post_to_facebook(link, message, photo) {
var wallPost = {
    access_token: page.access_token,
    link: link,
    message: message,
    picture: photo
};
FB.api("me/feed", "post", wallPost, function (response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
console.log(response);
      alert('Failure! ' + response.status + ' You may logout once and try again');
    } else {
      alert('Success! Post ID: ' + response);
    }
});
}
```

I am trying to post on form submit this is the code on submit:

```
 $('#add_new').click(function() {
        var formData = new FormData($('#add_new_form')[0]);
        formData.append("arabic_body", tinyMCE.get('ar_body').getContent());
        formData.append("english_body", tinyMCE.get('en_body').getContent());
        var url = getBaseUrl() + '/admin/add_new';
        $.ajax({
            url : url,  // Controller URL
            type : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            processData: false,
            success : function(data) {
                $('#nothing').fadeOut('slow');
                console.log(data);
                post_to_facebook(getBaseUrl() + '/Pages/view_new/' + data[0].id, data[0].ar_title, getBaseUrl() + '/news/' + data[0].img);
                $('#new').prepend('<tr id="row' + data[0].id + '"><td>' + data[0].id  + '</td><td><a href="Pages/view_new/' + data[0].id  + '">' + data[0].ar_title.substr(0,30)+' ...' + '</a></td><td>' + data[0].type_name + '</td><td>' + data[0].date_created + '</td><td><span style="color: red; cursor: pointer;" onclick="delete_new($(this));" id="del' + data[0].id  + '" class="delete_new">&#x2718;</span></td></tr>');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#shownew').trigger('click');
                $('#add_new_form')[0].reset();
            }
        });
        return false;
});
```

**UPDATE**

it post but as the user, not as page.

Comment: so....any errors? did you already debug your code? where is the problem exactly?

Comment: @luschn i debug it and it post to page as me as user but not as facebook page and iam trying to make the application post as page.

Comment: well, that´s the important part, in fact it´s the only relevant information. i will write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to post "as Page", you have to use a Page Token. Right now you are using a User Token, that´s why the posts show up as user posts. You need the permissions `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` for that.

Information about how to generate a Page Token:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/